# The correct position of "THERE" in a sentence, starting with a question word

Tags: relative-clauses

> 1. We do not know what  products **are there** on the market.
> 2. We do not know what products **there are** on the market.

I want to know whether we should change this sentence from its affirmative form when we use a question word as a noun clause.

What position for the word **"THERE"** is better in those sentences above?

Comment: The correct subordinate clause is 'what products there are on the market'; it is an interrogative complement clause (not a noun clause), so no inversion is required. The meaning is "We do not know the answer to the question 'What products are there on the market?"'

Comment: @BillJ can't ''what products'' ask for the subject?I have seen the sentence like ''Coats are there on the market".

Comment: 'Coats are there on the market' is not an interrogative, and 'there' has a locative meaning, not an existential one like that in your question.

Comment: In your main example, 'what products' is not the subject of the subordinate clause; it is predicative complement of 'are'. Think of it as 'there are what products?', in which 'there' is the subject.

Comment: Because the main verb is _know,_ the WH- clause is a form of indirect question. An indirect question uses statement word order (Wh-word +subject +verb,) so _We do not know what products there are on the market._ is correct.